# Husky A200, robot_pose_ekf

Tags: ros, navigation, clearpath, husky, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working with Clearpath Husky. I would like to merge all sensors over robot_pose_ekf (encoders and IMU). However, when I drive a robot, output from the filter is not correct. It is mostly okay for x axis, but prediction of y axis is not precise at all (robot turning creates a mess).

I would like to ask does anyone here has experience with Husky and if yes, could you please recommend how to configure ekf? I have tried using different covariances, but results are confusing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65397/husky-a200,-robot_pose_ekf/) by [el_lobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4940/el_lobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this problem as well. What kind of surface are you driving it on? I think that the reason the turning is off is due to excessive slip. I am in the process of testing this, so I will let you know what I find out.

EDIT: Once I started using the IMU on the Husky, it started working fine.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A skid steer vehicle like the Husky skids when its turning i.e. the wheel slips momentarily. Unfortunately, the encoders do no capture this slippage. This means the wheel odometry will typically report more rotational motion than is actually achieved. To compensate for this slippage we suggest that you combine this data with IMU data which is much better at estimating heading. This can be done with something like robot_pose_ekf which you have clearly done.

As for the accuracy of the robot_pose_ekf output, I'd love to hear about what specific accuracy and precision you are achieving. What kind of results are you seeing?

---

Originally posted by [pmukherj](https://answers.ros.org/users/3147/pmukherj/) with karma: 21 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1